# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in reducer

Tags: redux, promise

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on this code. I've looked at other solutions to my problem and they don't seem to apply to my scenario. The first dispatch is firing off as expected, but never makes it to the second dispatch (accept).

```
export function save() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return (
            dispatch(update())
        .then (() =>
            dispatch(accept())
        )
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `dispatch()` returns whatever action you passed in.

If you're using the `redux-thunk` middleware and dispatch a thunk function, then `dispatch()` returns whatever your thunk function returns.

So, that code will only work if `update` is a thunk, and it returns a promise.